# Firebase Auth and Google Calendar

Tags: javascript, firebase

What I am trying to do is use Firebase to authenticate with Google. Then get some data from Google Calendar.

I got the first part working. I can authenticate with Google and get user name, email ect., but once I add `calendar` to the `scope` it gives me 401 with `Error: invalid_scope`.

Is it even possible to get that kind of data with Firebase?

**HTML**

```
<a href="#auth" id="auth">login please</a>
<a href="#auth" id="calendar">calendar</a>
```

**JS**

```
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.2/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
      $("#auth").click(function() {
        var ref = new Firebase("https://<my-super-cool-app>.firebaseio.com/");

        ref.authWithOAuthPopup("google", function(error, authData) {
            if (error) {
                console.log("Login Failed!", error);
                console.log(error);
            } else {
                console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);
            }
        }, {
            "scope": "email, calendar"
        });

        return false;
      });
      $("#calendar").click(function() {
        $.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList', function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At present, Firebase only supports scopes [listed here](https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth#scopes). Thus, you can't use the `calendar*` scopes to authenticate with Firebase auth.

The only real workaround here, to avoid authenticating separately against Google and Firebase, would be to manually authenticate against Google with the requested scopes, then pass that OAuth token into Firebase's [authWithOAuthToken](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/authwithoauthtoken.html) method.

In other words, reverse the auth process to log in with Google and then re-use the token in Firebase.

Comment: What a bother to do all this. : S I wish Firebase would just extend their library for easy access to google Calendar...

Comment: By token do you mean refresh token access token or another kind of token?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work like this. I am just not sure how to use the information, but I got the auth part to work. Hope that it will help someone.

```
 Auth.$authWithOAuthPopup('google', {
                remember: "default",
                scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
                scope: 'email'
            })
            .then(function (authData) {
```