# Firebase Google Sign-In with Google Calendar API

Tags: angular, firebase, google-api, firebase-authentication

I'm currently using Firebase with Google Sign-In in an Angular project.

I would like to access the Google Calendar API. I think lot of steps described in the [google documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/js) are unnecessary since Firebase Google Sign-In already return an access token and a refresh token.

Below is the code from the [firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin?utm_campaign=Firebase_featureoverview_education_auth_en_07-26-16&utm_source=Firebase&utm_medium=yt-desc).

And it seems we can actually access the google API after the signInWithPopup method :

> This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.

```
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
  // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
  var token = result.credential.accessToken;
  // The signed-in user info.
  var user = result.user;
  // ...
});
```

Here is my code where i added the calendar in the scope.

```
let provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
provider.addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly");

this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
  // ...
});
```

So, what is the next step? How do i actually access the calendar and let say, return a list of my calendars or list of events?

Comment: Looks like this has been covered in various forms [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44476822/access-scope-data-after-firebase-authentication) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39914899/using-firebase-auth-to-access-the-google-calendar-api) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44231468/firebase-auth-and-google-calendar-creation) [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35195782/firebase-auth-and-google-calendar-using-polymer) [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28932427/firebase-auth-and-google-calendar)

Comment: [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49182671/is-it-possible-to-add-events-to-a-users-google-calendar-via-firebase-server-sid/49183647#49183647) looks pretty good and includes an example of accessing the calendar and links out to more ref docs.

Comment: Awesome, thank you @Kato. I wanted to make sure it was up to date :).

Comment: try this, hopefully it can help _https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bj15-6rBHQw&t=393s&index=2&list=PLvdMKdx5hXZgP_x9kfF9E2KwTBf4s8O6Y_